# XPath contains on two nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<Root>
 <Level>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Key>Lennon</Key>
    <Value>
       <Val>1</Val>
    </Value>
 </Level>
 <Level>
    <Name>Fred</Name>
    <Key>Hi</Key>
    <Value>
       <Val>2</Val>
    </Value>
 </Level>
</Root>
```

I need a XPath which will use 'contains' about Name **and** Key.

The expected result is the 'Value/Val'.

For inputs: Name - John, Key - Lennon

I expect: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[Name='John'][Key='Lennon']/Value/Val
```

This selects any `Val` element that is a child of any `Value` element that is a child of an element that has a child `Name` with string value the string "John" and that has a child `Key` with string value the string "Lennon:, and that (the parent of `Value`) is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**In case you need just the string value of the selected `Val` element, use:**

```
string(/*/*[Name='John'][Key='Lennon']/Value/Val)
```

**In addition to this, if it is known that any `Val` value is a number, use:**

```
number(/*/*[Name='John'][Key='Lennon']/Value/Val)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick

```
/Root/Level[Name[1] = "John" and Key[1] = "Lennon"]/Value/Val[1]
```

Comment: Yes, except you can probably drop all three "[1]" predicates. I say "probably" because we don't know very much about the possible inputs.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKay. You know, I usually test XPath in SQL Server MS, and SQL has it's own subset of XPath. Do you know some good ways to test XPath, something like sqlfiddle.com for SQL or jsfiddle.com for javascript?

Comment: @RomanPekar, One good (not only because I wrote it :) ) tool to use is the XPath Visualizer.  It is completely free and open source and can be obtained here: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html